# Static Files won't show with Django

Tags: css, django

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
........
<img src="{% static 'images/parralax/spaces.jpg' %}"  width = 250px  />
<body>
```

Above code won't show the image I have as a background. Really unsure how to fix this issue.

Here are my setting files. I think the issue is coming from linking to CSS not working.
Thanks in advance!

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [.....
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,  ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR #where to look for files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' #where to serve files from on url
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Space.wsgi.application'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')

.....


.....
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^Spaces/', include('Spaces.urls')),
    #Django Admin
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #User Management
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),
    path(r'^users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_DIR)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_DIR)
```

Please help :)

Cheers!

Comment: `{% static 'images/parallax/home/9.jpg' %}` what url does it produce? Which response do you get when opening this url?

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Spaces/images/parallax/home/9.jpg

Comment: What are STATICFILES_DIRS, STATIC_URL values? Did you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: Given config would result in `127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/parallax/home/9.jpg` because of `static` function usage and `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` value. And I assume you did not run `collectstatic` and you're trying to reach image located inside `Spaces` app subfolders. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you running with `DEBUG = True` or `DEBUG = False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue.

I was linking the wrong folder the entire time. Silly mistake.

Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you write this line top of your html file:

```
{% load static %}
```

second point is close your div with :

```
</div>
```

and write something into div or provide a 'height' attribute for your dive:

```
<div class="full-screen force-full-screen" style="background: url('{% static 'images/parallax/home/9.jpg' %}') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;height: 100px;">
```

third point : be sure this two line is in your settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use

{% load static from staticfiles %}

Answer (score 1):

Use `{% load static %}` at the start of your HTML files(except for `base.html`) instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`.

And make sure this is available in your settings.py

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
     )
     STATIC_URL = '/static/'`